# Linux Mint Rebecca - No sound - Dummy Output - integrated soundcard

Tags: linux, audio, linux-mint, sound-card

I have been running Linux Mint Rebecca for a little while now and everything has been working fine, but yesterday I lost sound and now it only says Dummy Output. Its an integrated soundcard.

```
pactl list sinks

Sink #0
State: SUSPENDED
Name: auto_null
Description: Dummy Output
Driver: module-null-sink.c
Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 10
Mute: no
Volume: 0:  85% 1:  85%
        0: -4,19 dB 1: -4,19 dB
        balance 0,00
Base Volume: 100%
             0,00 dB
Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
Properties:
    device.description = "Dummy Output"
    device.class = "abstract"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card"
Formats:
    pcm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I use linux mint 17.1 rebecca, I think. My laptop is lenovo. I googled and looked on various sources, one of them was: [Linux Mint and sound problems](https://superuser.com/questions/852486/linux-mint-and-sound-problems). when I enter `pactl list sinks` code on terminal, it gives me 2 sinks, and both of them were suspended. I tried to set default sink etc., no way, there was no sound on my laptop. There is volume control on menu (start) bar, so I changed devices from there and tried again and again, restarting etc. And finally sound is fixed and working now. And when I enter that above-shown pactl etc code I still get both sinks susspended. So I suggest you to try to fix it with "Volume control" settings.

Comment: Thanks for the input but after messing around with the settings and trying alot of different stuff I got feed up and kicked out Mint and installed Centos instead.